# Multithreaded pooled server listening on multiple ports in Java -

Tags: java, multithreading, server, threadpool

I am trying to figure out how to create a Java multithreaded server that can listen on multiple ports and have threadpools for each of the ports it accepts requests from.

I have already implemented a fucntioning multithread pooled server listening on a singl eport, as seen here:

```
public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }
        openSocketServer();
        while (!isStopped()) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (isStopped()) {
                    System.out.println("Server Stopped.");
                    break;
                }
                throw new RuntimeException("Error with accepting client connection", e);
            }
            this.threadPool.submit(new HandlerRichieste(clientSocket, this));
        }
        this.threadPool.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Server stopped");
    }
```

And I managed to implement a server listening on multiple ports with the NIO library; the problem with this implementation is that it only uses a single thread to handle the requests coming from the different ports, therefore handling them sequentially and killing performance:

```
Selector selector = Selector.open();

int[] ports = {4000,4001,6000};

for (int port : ports) {
   ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
   server.configureBlocking(false);

   server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
   // from here we are only interested when accept evens occur on this socket
   server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT); 
}

while (selector.isOpen()) {
   selector.select();
   Set readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
   Iterator iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();
      if (key.isAcceptable()) {
         SocketChannel client = server.accept(); //SERVER CANNOT BE RESOLVED!!!!
         Socket socket = client.socket();
         // create new thread to deal with the connection coming from that port (closing both socket and client when done)
      }
   }
}
```

How can I merge them - resulting in a server listening on multiple ports that has a threadpool for every port?
Is it even possible to make a multithread pooled server that is listening to multuple ports without using the NIO library?
If so, can anybody show me the mechanism for having a threadpool for each port without Java NIO?

Comment: If you're using a `Selector`, the normal way is to use one thread that does nothing but service selector events.  Then when you get a packet / some work to do, you send the packet to a separate thread pool to execute the work.  The selector thread then just immediately returns to servicing the selector.

Comment: If you want to see some real working code, check out the Apache Web Server source, which also uses the `select()` or `poll()` call.  I believe the relevant code is in `listen.c` : https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/trunk/server/listen.c

Comment: @markspace Thank you, this is exactly what I've done in my implementation of the 'server listening on multiple ports' with NIO's Selector (I didn't add the entire code as to give a minimum reproducible example, but as you can see from the code there's a single thread listening on all ports and sending packets to the separate threadpool). Unfortunately, since it makes the servicing of selection events sequential, I need to have multiple threadpools - one per port - so that if there's multiple request coming from multiple ports, I won't be stuck with only servicing one port at a time.

Comment: @markspace The Apache Web Server source is really interesting and it definitely reiterates what the standard is - apparently what I need can't be done with Selectors (NIO library). Still, I'm truly in need of advice as to how to modify the first multithreaded server implementation in the question so that it can accept requests coming froma  given set of ports (as the "create a threadpool per port" part would be pretty easy to implement after that).

Comment: @markspace Creating different multithread pooled server - ove for each port - would perhaps solve my issue? Although how would I go about implementing that route (I'm a newbie)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already able to create a server with one thread waiting for connections on one port and serving incoming connections with threads from one specific pool.

What stops you from creating this pattern three times? Then you are listening on three ports and serving incoming connections with threads from three specific thread pools. The only thing you need to watch out:
Waiting for a connection on one socket may block the thread.

As a solution just create three threads that are listening for one port each.

Comment: Such a simple solution, thank you! A new socket would be implemented for each port, no NIO required!